# mysql insert into.. on duplicate key update - auto_increment issue

Tags: mysql

I need to perform bulk `INSERT IGNORE` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and I'm facing the following problem.

I perform 20 million updates daily on a table of around 20 million. Only a few dozen thousand new rows are added daily.

If I use `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0` I'm losing concurrent performance, but the ID increments only when rows are inserted.

If I use `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 1` I gain concurrency, but the ID field increments by 20 million daily, and it would max out an `INT` in under 4 months.

I could use a `BIGINT` and I wouldn't run out of ID space even with updates, but this seems a bit hacky. Is this the preferable solution in my case?

Comment: Generally, there is nothing wrong with bigints. It will increase your index sizes a bit (by 20million*4byte per index). If you do not like that, you have the other option. Additionally, you have the option to check if the rows already exists before you try to insert it (so first update all rows that exists, then insert the rows that don't exist yet). It will depend on your process and requirements if that is acceptable and fast enough or not. It makes your process a bit more complicated (you may have to import it to a 2nd temptable, will have to adept the query if you change unique keys, ...)

Comment: im currently using int but changing to bigint isnt a problem since each row takes up considerable size, an extra 4 bytes will not have any impact. however, i did think about doing selects, and maybe ill try that to see performance difference.